# Relation between exact sequences and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, exact-sequence

Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says that if $A $ is every ideal in $k [x_1,\dots x_n] $, $k $ an algebraically closed field, then $I (V (A)) = \sqrt A;$ I'm using the notation of Mumford, that should be well known.

Now take the ring $\mathcal D$ defined in this way: its elements are the ideals of $k [x_1,\dots x_n] $, the product $A\cdot B $ is the ideal $ (A \cup B )$, and the sum $A+B $ is the ideal $A\cap B $. With these definitions, $\mathcal D$ is actually a ring. 
Then take the ring $\mathcal S $ defined in this way: its elements are the algebraically closed sets of $\mathbb A^n $, the product $\Sigma_1\cdot \Sigma_2 $ is $ \Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2 $, and the sum $\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2 $ is $\Sigma_1\cup \Sigma_2 $. Clearly $\mathcal S$ is a ring too. Take the homomorphism of rings $V$ and $I $ as above: consider a sequence $$\dots \to \mathcal D \xrightarrow {V } \mathcal S \xrightarrow {I } \mathcal D \xrightarrow {V } \mathcal S \to \dots$$ One cannot say that it is exact. However if we restrict to the set $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal D $ of ideals in a radical ideal $A'$ (so $A'=\sqrt {A'}$), we have the sequence $$\dots \to \mathcal A \xrightarrow {V } 0 \xrightarrow {I } \mathcal A \xrightarrow {V } 0 \to \dots$$ Notice that this sequence is well defined because every element in $\mathcal A $ is sent from $V $ to the same set $\Sigma $ (so we use the ring with only one element, namely $0$) and $I (0)=0$. In fact, $I (\Sigma)=A' $, and considering the way we defined products and sums in $\mathcal D $, if we restrict to $\mathcal A$ is clear that $A'$ is the $0$ of $\mathcal A$. So it's trivial that the sequence is exact.

I have a very poor knowledge of algebraic geometry and categories; does what I wrote makes sense? I haven't found anything about it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $\mathcal D$ is not a ring, Let $R = k[x_1,...,x_n]$, then the ideal $R$ is the zero of $\mathcal D$ and for $\mathcal D$ to be a ring then for every ideal $A$ there has to exist an ideal $B$ such that $ A + B = 0$ i.e $A \cap B = R$ but clearly this can't happen if $A \neq R$ since $R = A \cap B \subset A$ and thus $R \subset A$ and $R = A$. Contradiction. $\mathcal S$ is not a ring either since there's obviously no inverse to $\cup$. You can't remove elements by taking the union with some other set. $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal D$ are what's called "semirings", rings without additive inverse.

Comment: Sorry @NoelLundström I really forgot to check that property. I have only one more question: in $\mathcal D $ there are elements $r $ (namely the radical ideals) such that $ar=r$ for some $a \in \mathcal D$ (namely when $a $ is a ideal contained in the ideal $r $). Is this possible even in a ring? It seems to me that in a ring $R $ we could have a subring $S $ and an element $r\in S $ such that $sr=r $ or $sr=-r $ for every $s\in S $. Am I right or am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: Sure, I don't see any problem. And just one more thing, you can't define exact sequences in the category of rings since you don't have a $0-$object. In the category of semirings however there is a $0-$oject, just take the unique semiring with only one element. Semirings don't have to have a $1$. So your original question makes sense in the category of semirings.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood; why does $\{0\}$ is not a ring? I thought it was the only ring in which the $0$ and the $1$ coincide. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes well it is not a $0-$object in the category of rings with $1$. It is a terminal object but not an initial one. $\mathbb Z$ is the initial object. A $0-$object in a category is an object that is both terminal and initial.

Comment: Of course you're right, I still forgot that $\mathcal D$ is not a ring but a semi-ring.